# GLMs for exponential families - why is the canonical link invertible?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, linear-regression, exponential-family

I am studying GLMs for exponential families and wondering how the density of exponential families gives rise to a canonical link function.

Following the notation from Fahrmeier (Regression), the density of an exponential family is

$$f(y \mid \theta) = \text{exp}\big (\frac{y \theta - b(\theta)}{\Phi}w + c(y,\Phi,w) \big 
).$$

In this notation, $\mu = E[Y] = b'(\theta)$.

Also, in typical GLM notation, one often writes $g(E[Y \mid X]) = X \beta$, or $E[Y \mid X] = g^{-1}(X \beta)$.

My question: How do I automatically get a canonical link for each distribution in the exponential family?
**If $b'$ were invertible and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$**, then I could simply set $g = (b')^{-1}$ and try to predict $\theta$ with the linear predictor. But why is $b'$ always invertible and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$? Many sources just tend to write down the parameter mapping $\theta(\mu)$ and it's inverse without stating explicit assumptions.
Thanks!